# Vectorising Iterrows/Itertuples on Time Series Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a series of dataframes containing OHLC data from Yahoo Finance, sorted by ascending dates. I want to test some things for my economics class so built a simple script using `iterrows`. It was painfully slow but it is what I knew.

To speed it up I tried using `itertuples`. This did improve things but the script is still too slow. Here is the applicable extract:

```
for row in ticker_df.itertuples(index=True):
    # Open rules
    if not in_position:
        rule_one = row.PCClose > row.PCSMA20    
        if rule_one:    
            rule_two = row.PCSMA20 > row.PCSMA50    
            if rule_two:    
                rule_three = row.PCSMA100 > row.PCSMA300    
                if rule_three:    
                    rule_five = row.PCClose > (row.PCWeekLow52 * 1.9)    
                    if rule_five:    
                        rule_six = row.PCClose > (row.PCWeekHigh52 * 0.5)    
                        if rule_six:    
                            if row.WeekLow3 >= (row.WeekHigh3 * 0.5):    
                                # Check if broken out
                                if row.PCClose > row.WeekHigh3:    
                                    rule_eight = row.PctCh > 1.2    
                                    if rule_eight:    
                                        in_position = True    
    if in_position:    
        # Close rules
        if row.PCSMA20 < row.PCSMA50:    
            in_position = False
```

I am now trying to vectorise my approach and have incorporated the above open rules into a numpy select:

```
open_rules = [(ticker_df["PCClose"] > ticker_df["PCSMA20"]) & (ticker_df["PCSMA20"] > ticker_df["PCSMA50"]) &
              (ticker_df["PCSMA100"] > ticker_df["PCSMA300"]) & (ticker_df["PCClose"] > (ticker_df["PCWeekLow52"] * 1.9)) &
              (ticker_df["PCClose"] > (ticker_df["PCWeekHigh52"] * 0.5)) & (ticker_df['WeekLow3'] >= (ticker_df['WeeHigh3'] * 0.5)) &
              (ticker_df['PCPctCh'] > 1.2)]

open_rules_met = ["Open"]

ticker_df["Trades"] = np.select(open_rules, open_rules_met, default='NA')
```

This works faster to define the open positions but the problem I have is how to then identify the closing positions.

As the iterrorws/itertuples approach loops through the rows sequentially I can simply set the `in_position` flag to true then continue iterating down the rows to check if the close rules are met. But I cannot work out how to achieve this with a vectorised appoach. Obviously the close can only happen on a date that is after the open date.

Is there a way of doing this?

Edit:

The code is simply comparing the values in one column with values in another column or fixed values. Here is an extract of a ticker_df:

| Date | Open | High | Low | PCClose | Adj Close | Volume | Ticker | NextDayOpen | PCSMA20 | PCSMA50 | PCSMA100 | PCSMA300 | VMA | PCWeekLow52 | PCWeekHigh52 | WeekLow3 | WeekHigh3 | PctCh |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15/09/2023 | 143.5850067 | 144.9499969 | 142.1000061 | 142.75 | 142.75 | 74786400 | ABNB | 141.9299927 | 135.3800007 | 138.8851004 | 125.7562335 | 118.8517251 | 7123686 | 82.48999786 | 153.3300018 | 124.7200012 | 147.5 | 0.215381961 |
| 18/09/2023 | 141.9299927 | 144.3999939 | 141.1900024 | 142.5500031 | 142.5500031 | 7351400 | ABNB | 141.8600006 | 136.254501 | 139.1297003 | 125.9807669 | 119.0875751 | 7207752 | 82.48999786 | 153.3300018 | 125.7900009 | 147.5 | 0.15605763 |
| 19/09/2023 | 141.8600006 | 142.5700073 | 139.7700043 | 141.8500061 | 141.8500061 | 6674100 | ABNB | 142.7599945 | 137.1470013 | 139.3325003 | 126.1503002 | 119.2861252 | 7260194 | 82.48999786 | 153.3300018 | 126.1549988 | 147.5 | 0.142319112 |
| 20/09/2023 | 142.7599945 | 143.2700043 | 137.9499969 | 138.0099945 | 138.0099945 | 5189000 | ABNB | 135.5549927 | 137.6935009 | 139.3419003 | 126.2645669 | 119.4698252 | 7163062 | 82.48999786 | 153.3300018 | 130.6100006 | 147.5 | 0.167105521 |
| 21/09/2023 | 135.5549927 | 135.9799957 | 132.3899994 | 132.75 | 132.75 | 8514300 | ABNB | 133.7100067 | 137.9245007 | 139.2565002 | 126.2361669 | 119.6285752 | 7221676 | 82.48999786 | 153.3300018 | 130.6100006 | 147.5 | 0.088406871 |
| 22/09/2023 | 133.7100067 | 134.1840057 | 131.1199951 | 132.1999969 | 132.1999969 | 4278500 | ABNB | 130.8000031 | 138.2985004 | 139.0987003 | 126.1880335 | 119.7970251 | 7196600 | 82.48999786 | 153.3300018 | 131.5500031 | 147.5 | 0.061660261 |
| 25/09/2023 | 130.8000031 | 134.25 | 130.8000031 | 134.1399994 | 134.1399994 | 4154500 | ABNB | 132.7799988 | 138.7160004 | 138.9147003 | 126.2049668 | 120.0021251 | 7149758 | 82.48999786 | 153.3300018 | 132.1999969 | 147.5 | 0.113263132 |
| 26/09/2023 | 132.7799988 | 133.9400024 | 131.1699982 | 132.2799988 | 132.2799988 | 4194000 | ABNB | 133.8000031 | 139.0222504 | 138.6531003 | 126.2283002 | 120.2060251 | 7118522 | 82.48999786 | 153.3300018 | 132.1999969 | 147.5 | 0.129314706 |
| 27/09/2023 | 133.8000031 | 134.8999939 | 131.2200012 | 134.0299988 | 134.0299988 | 3771300 | ABNB | 133.6499939 | 139.1112503 | 138.4031003 | 126.2737668 | 120.4020251 | 7111450 | 82.48999786 | 153.3300018 | 132.1999969 | 147.5 | 0.13340759 |
| 28/09/2023 | 133.6499939 | 138.2299957 | 132.8800049 | 136.4700012 | 136.4700012 | 4058900 | ABNB | 138.0500031 | 139.4042503 | 138.2218002 | 126.3467669 | 120.6108751 | 7093256 | 82.48999786 | 153.3300018 | 132.1999969 | 147.5 | 0.175598599 |
| 29/09/2023 | 138.0500031 | 141.0749969 | 136.3600006 | 137.2100067 | 137.2100067 | 4781100 | ABNB | 136.5500031 | 139.6872505 | 138.0604004 | 126.4429669 | 120.8190252 | 7103952 | 82.48999786 | 153.3300018 | 132.1999969 | 147.5 | 0.315753949 |
| 02/10/2023 | 136.5500031 | 138 | 135.3600006 | 136.5599976 | 136.5599976 | 3488300 | ABNB |  | 139.8807503 | 137.8162003 | 126.5298336 | 121.0351252 | 6937828 | 82.48999786 | 153.3300018 | 132.1999969 | 147.5 | 0.348501294 |

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you want to do by reading your long code and make corrections. It would be better to explain what you want to do through an example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please include an example of your dataframe in your [mre]. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/843953)

Comment: Thanks guys. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

The code you're writing is not maintainable, try something more like:

```
from functools import partial

def add(array,index,value):
    array[index]+=value
    
def multiply(array,index,value):
    array[index]*=value
    
a = list(range(10))
print("Before rules:")
print(a)
print("#"*20)
rules_to_actions = {
    ('Rule 1', True) : partial(print,"Rule1"),
    ('Rule 2', False) : partial(print,"Rule2"),
    ('Rule 3', True) : partial(add,a,3,-10),
    ('Rule 4', True) : partial(print,a[4]),
    ('Rule 5', False) : partial(print,"Rule5"),
    ('Rule 6', True) : partial(multiply,a,2,5),
}

for rule in sorted(rules_to_actions): # To apply the rules in order, you can pass key=lambda x: y to sort the rules
    if rule[1]:
        rules_to_actions[rule]()
print("After rules:")
print(a)
print("#"*20)
```

you just then need to define the appropriate action for each rule, as well as a away to sort the rules in the desired order